# Using select2 with datatables to filter on multple values

Tags: datatables, jquery-select2

Im currently trying to filter each column of my datatable using a select2 dropdown.

My code currently filters correctly without the multiple tag on the select tag, but once I add the multiple value to my select tag I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a.replace is not a function
```

I have been trying to adapt the following datatables javascript:
[link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Here is what I have currently:

```
$('#caseTable').DataTable( {
            initComplete: function () {
                var x = 0;
                this.api().columns().every( function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select class="search2" multiple="multiple"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $('.dropdown'+x)) 
                        .on( 'change', function () { 
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ) //find this value in this column, if it matches, draw it into the table.
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option id="'+d+'"value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    } );

                    x++   
                } );
                $(".search2").select2();

            }
} );
```

EDIT: I managed to fix it. I needed to store the multiple values into an array, and then pipe the values together to search for each individual value.
Here are the changes I made to the .on('change') function.

```
.on( 'change', function () { //when an option is selected
        var val = new Array();
        //set val to current element in the dropdown.
        val = $(this).val();

        if (val.length > 1){

          valString = val.toString();
          valPiped =  valString.replace(/,/g,"|")

             column
               .search( valPiped ? '^'+valPiped+'$' : '', true, false ) //find this value in this column, if it matches, draw it into the table.
               .draw();
         } else if (val.length == 1) {
             column
                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ) //find this value in this column, if it matches, draw it into the table.
                 .draw();
         } else {
             column
                .search('',true,false)
                .draw();
         }
} );
```

Comment: Write your fix into an answer and mark it answered so others can see that it was answered easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I needed to store the multiple values into an array, and then pipe the values together to search for each individual value. Here are the changes I made to the .on('change') function.

```
.on( 'change', function () { //when an option is selected
    var val = new Array();
    //set val to current element in the dropdown.
    val = $(this).val();

    if (val.length > 1){

      valString = val.toString();
      valPiped =  valString.replace(/,/g,"|")

         column
           .search( valPiped ? '^'+valPiped+'$' : '', true, false ) //find this value in this column, if it matches, draw it into the table.
           .draw();
     } else if (val.length == 1) {
         column
            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ) //find this value in this column, if it matches, draw it into the table.
             .draw();
     } else {
         column
            .search('',true,false)
            .draw();
     }
} );
```